# Are there known paradoxes regarding a detector that was, before use, entangled with a particle it detects?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

Is it possible to design a system where a detector is entangled with the particle state it detects (before it is detected), and to create a paradox from this?

Upon observance of a state by the detector, a correlation between the particle and any entangled particles will instantly occur; fi a reverse spin. What if these happen in the detector and affect detection?

I cannot think of any paradoxes or “deadlock” scenarios but I was wondering if literature knows of any.

I think it *could* be somewhat of an argument against traditional simulation theories.

Comment: You can read up on "Wigner's friend", see e.g. [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend) and references therein.

Comment: Measurement _is_ entanglement.

Comment: I know @my2cts but that happens “too late”

Comment: @my2cts that's, at best, an overly vague statement. A "measurement" is something you perform on a system. Entanglement is a property of a system. So no, they are not the same thing.

Comment: @glS I mean that measurement is a form of entanglement. Hope that is clear enough.

Comment: @my2cts not really. It's just a wrong statement (or more precisely, I'd say it's a meaningless one). Sure, measurements is how you can detect entanglement, if that's what you meant. That's not the same as saying that measurement "is" or "is a form of" entanglement.

Comment: @glS Your statement that "A 'measurement' is something you perform on a system" is hilarious. Acknowledgement of ignorance is the root of wisdom!